# Address Search Bar in Angular with Observable to url with recommendations

Tags: angular, service, autocomplete, rxjs, esri

```
export class AddressSuggestionsService {
  private addressSuggestionsUrl =
    'http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/findAddressCandidates?f=json&singleLine=';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getAddressSuggestions(term: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.httpClient
      .get(
        `${this.addressSuggestionsUrl}${term}&outfields=Match_addr,Addr_type=PointAddress`
      )
      .pipe(
        tap((data) => console.log('All: ' + JSON.stringify(data))),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
}
```

I'm building out an auto-complete Search Bar for address suggestions in Angular. Address-Suggestions come from a third party provider in URL. I'm having trouble extracting a certain key from the Observable response. The key is named *Candidates*. Is it possible to extract only key from an Observable Response at service? [github repo](https://github.com/omar-nav/addressSearchBar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the map operator to convert the response into something else.

It's a good idea to create types for your responses.
it will make it easier for you with code completion in vs code.

```
interface AddressSuggestionResponse {
  Candidates: string[]
}

export class AddressSuggestionsService {
  private addressSuggestionsUrl =
    'http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/findAddressCandidates?f=json&singleLine=';

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  getAddressSuggestions(term: string): Observable<string[]> {
    return this.httpClient
      .get<AddressSuggestionResponse>(
        `${this.addressSuggestionsUrl}${term}&outfields=Match_addr,Addr_type=PointAddress`
      )
      .pipe(
        map((data) => data.Candidates),
        catchError(this.handleError)
      );
  }
}
```

Comment: that was it! final solution below

Answer (score 0):

```
  searchAddress(term: string): Observable<Address[]> {
    let url = `${this.endpoint}${term}&maxLocations=5&location=30.270,-97.745&distance=80467.2`;

    if (!term.trim()) {
      return of([]);
    }
    return this.httpClient
      .get<Address[]>(url)
      .pipe(
        map((data) => data['candidates']),
          catchError(this.handleError<Address[]>('addresses', []))
        );
  }
  private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
      console.log(`failed: ${error.message}`);
      return of(result as T);
    };
  }
}
```